# Fatal Exception, inflateexception

Tags: android, fatal-error, inflate-exception, window-managers

I'm trying to make a pong like game. I've been following a tutorial from here http://mikeyhogarth.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/how-to-develop-pong-for-android/, but the tutorial had a fixed height and width to display the game. I've been trying to modify the code to find the actual screen dimensions, and use those instead of the fixed settings. So the game will scale no matter the screen size. The GameState.java is where I put the getWidth and GetHeight.
These two line were the original screen size lines from GameState.

Original

```
//screen width and height
    final int _screenWidth = 300;
    final int _screenHeight = 420;
```

Modified

```
//screen width and height
    final int _screenWidth = getWidth(null);
    final int _screenHeight = getHeight(null);
```

MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<com.dbryant423.classicpong.GameView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

GameView.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class GameView extends SurfaceView  implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
private GameThread _thread;

public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    //So we can listen for events...
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    setFocusable(true); 

    //and instantiate the thread
    _thread = new GameThread(holder, context, new Handler());
}  

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {
    return _thread.getGameState().keyPressed(keyCode, msg);
}

//Implemented as part of the SurfaceHolder.Callback interface
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    //Mandatory, just swallowing it for this example

}

//Implemented as part of the SurfaceHolder.Callback interface
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    _thread.start();
}

//Implemented as part of the SurfaceHolder.Callback interface
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    _thread.stop();
}

private float _x = 0;
private float _y = 0;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
_x = event.getX();
_y = event.getY();
}
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
final float xdiff = (_x - event.getX());
final float ydiff = (_y - event.getY());
_thread.getGameState().surfaceTouched(_x, _y);

_x = event.getX();
_y = event.getY();
}
return true;
}
}
```

GameThread.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class GameThread extends Thread {

/** Handle to the surface manager object we interact with */
private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
private Paint _paint;
private GameState _state;

public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context, Handler handler)
{
_surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
_paint = new Paint();
_state = new GameState();
}

@Override
public void run() {
while(true)
{
Canvas canvas = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
_state.update();
_state.draw(canvas,_paint);
_surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
}

public GameState getGameState()
{
return _state;
}
}
```

GameState.java

```
    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Point;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.view.Display;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.WindowManager;


    public class GameState {



 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)  public static int
 getWidth(Context mContext){
        int width=0;
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)       mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>12){                   
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            width = size.x;
        }
        else{
            width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
        }
        return width;   }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)   public static int
 getHeight(Context mContext){
        int height=0;
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>12){               
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            height = size.y;
        }else{          
            height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
        }
        return height;          }


    //screen width and height
    final int _screenWidth = getWidth(null);
    final int _screenHeight = getHeight(null);

    //The ball
    final int _ballSize = 10;
    int _ballX = 100;   int _ballY = 100;
    int _ballVelocityX = 3;     int _ballVelocityY = 3;

    //The bats
    final int _batLength = 75;  final int _batHeight = 10;
    int _topBatX = (_screenWidth/2) - (_batLength / 2);
    final int _topBatY = 20;
    int _bottomBatX = (_screenWidth/2) - (_batLength / 2);  
    final int _bottomBatY = 400;
    final int _batSpeed = 3;


    public GameState()
    {
    }

    //The update method
    public void update() {

    _ballX += _ballVelocityX;
    _ballY += _ballVelocityY;

    //DEATH!
    if(_ballY > _screenHeight || _ballY < 0)        
    {_ballX = 100;  _ballY = 100;}      //Collisions with the sides

    if(_ballX > _screenWidth || _ballX < 0)
                _ballVelocityX *= -1;   //Collisions with the bats      

    if(_ballX > _topBatX && _ballX < _topBatX+_batLength && _ballY < _topBatY)      
                     _ballVelocityY *= -1;  //Collisions with the bats      

    if(_ballX > _bottomBatX && _ballX < _bottomBatX+_batLength 
                    && _ballY > _bottomBatY)
                           _ballVelocityY *= -1;
    }

    public boolean keyPressed(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg)
    {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) //left
    {
    _topBatX += _batSpeed; _bottomBatX -= _batSpeed;
    }

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT) //right
    {
    _topBatX -= _batSpeed; _bottomBatX += _batSpeed;
    }

    return true;
    }

    //the draw method
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {

    //Clear the screen
    canvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);

    //set the colour
    paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);

    //draw the ball
    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(_ballX,_ballY,_ballX + _ballSize,_ballY + _ballSize),
                                 paint);

    //draw the bats
    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(_topBatX, _topBatY, _topBatX + _batLength,
                                          _topBatY + _batHeight), paint); //top bat
    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(_bottomBatX, _bottomBatY, _bottomBatX + _batLength, 
                                          _bottomBatY + _batHeight), paint); //bottom bat

    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(505, 500, 500, 0), paint); //Right Wall
    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(5, 500, 0, 0), paint); //Left Wall

    }


    public boolean surfaceTouched(float posX, float posY) {
    _topBatX = (int) posX;
    _bottomBatX = (int) posX;

    return true;
    }
    }
```

And finally the logcat:

```
    12-01 14:32:43.861: D/AndroidRuntime(2318): Shutting down VM
12-01 14:32:43.861: W/dalvikvm(2318): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415c3b90)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318): Process: com.dbryant423.classicpong, PID: 2318
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dbryant423.classicpong/com.dbryant423.classicpong.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class com.dbryant423.classicpong.GameView
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class com.dbryant423.classicpong.GameView
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at com.dbryant423.classicpong.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     ... 11 more
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     ... 22 more
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at com.dbryant423.classicpong.GameState.getWidth(GameState.java:20)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at com.dbryant423.classicpong.GameState.<init>(GameState.java:50)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at com.dbryant423.classicpong.GameThread.<init>(GameThread.java:20)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     at com.dbryant423.classicpong.GameView.<init>(GameView.java:24)
12-01 14:32:43.871: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):     ... 25 more
12-01 14:32:46.613: I/Process(2318): Sending signal. PID: 2318 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is here

```
<com.dbryant423.classicpong.GameView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

did you add your activity to the manifest?

```
<activity android:name=".GameView">
   <intent-filter>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.GAMEVIEW"></category>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT"></action>
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I have added it to the manifest.Do you have a suggestion on how to fix the rest? when I switch to graphical view for activity_main.xml I get a com.dbryant423.classicpong.GameView failed to instantiate

Comment: you should use View.isInEditMode()

Comment: Thanks, that helps to see while editing in eclipse. But none of that solves the issues of the activity not displaying correctly. You tell me where the error is, but you don't give me a solution to correct the error.